# What could be causing my RAD Studio Android app to crash upon opening on the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash-reports, delphi-11-alexandria, rad-studio

I have some problem with RAD Studio when i make apk android in emulator the program run but crash and close. i try again run from android emulator error appear messages "myandroidapp keep closing".
I used Rad Studio 11.3, anyone help me please i was confused.

I try setting emulator on android studio no problem but when build apk in rad studio the app crash and close immedietly. i try rad studio uninstall and install again running app build apk and running on emulator the problem still appear.